# JDBC Connection error persists

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am using MySQL Workbench (5.6.19). It has several connections among which the table that i want to access is in "Connection1"(name of connection). Connection Host: 122.0.0.0 . My database name is "sorder". user = "root", password = "password",port = 3306.

Here's my piece of code:

```
try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {

                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true); 
                pw.println("Driver Connection Failed."); 
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");  
    Connection connection = null;

    try 
    {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sorder","root", "password");

    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

My driver connection failed. Plus i am not sure what my path Strin url should be since there are more than 1 connections in mySQL workbench.

error :

```
-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
Driver Connection Failed.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.jsp.NewFile_jsp._jspService(NewFile_jsp.java:65)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
```

I followed whatever suggestions i got in different forums, like:

- reassured that JAR file is there in build path.
- reassured that JAR file is there in Window>Prefernces>Java>Build Path>Classpath variable
- JAR file explicitily in WEB-INF/lib buildpath.

Thankful for any suggestions.

Regards.

Comment: How are you running this piece of code? The mysql connector jar should be available in runtime. Therefore it doesn't matter that it's in your build path.

Comment: @Eran yes, JAR file is there in specified path during run time.

Comment: i tried "telnet mydomainname.com 3306" in cmd, where mydomainanme is replaced with my actual domain name. Connection fails. I am writing connection code from within javabeans in a JSP page for a drop down. mySQL server and workbench is also in local pc.

Comment: and i have checked in firewallsettings, port 3306 is not blocked.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the connection URL or the location of your DB. Your code simply doesn't find `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` at runtime. In what container are you running your server code? Tomcat? Something else?

Comment: @Eran yes, i am using tomcat. i am using eclipse juno in windows XP. When i am creating a dynamic project, web.xml is not automatically getting created. so when we manually created a xml file and added <welcome-file-list>, it worked. similarly while i am creating a servlet class from New list(not manually), it does not recognise HttpServlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we manually created a xml file and added welcome-file-list, it worked. Default xml file was missing.